# Find-and-replace with python list

Tags: python, list

Is there a fancy method for replacing a specific value of a list with another value?
Like a shortcut for this:

```py
>>> l = list(range(10))
>>> replacing = 3
>>> l[l.index(replacing)] = 4
>>> l
[0, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

With the example I gave it's easy enough to do via the `[l.index()]`, but when the list reference is a few dots away it starts getting ugly.
It would be so much prettier to do something like this:

```
>>> some.thing.very.far.away.list = list(range(10))
>>> some.thing.very.far.away.list.replace(3, 4)
```

**Edit:**
I forgot to say *why*.
I want to **edit** the **same** list, and only edit **one** of the values.
I'm actually kind of supprized that lists doesn't have a built-in method like `list.replace(old, new[, max)`, considering that strings do and it seems like python has built-ins for just about everying.

Comment: You cann't define a variable `some.thing.very.far.away.list` like this?

Comment: Note that your solution only treat the first occurrence of the item to replace

Comment: Lists are mutable structures, so you can pass them to a function and the function can modify them.  That way you don't have to repeat the verbose variable name multiple times.

Comment: @AnnZen I haven't accepted any answers because none of them quite give me the answer I was wanting (see my edit). Your answer was good, but I only wanted to replace _one_ element. Sorry I forgot to specify in the original question.

Comment: @cajomar I updated.

Comment: I just want to add that your list is probably ill-defined. You have a list in which the index always equals the value. That is kind of useless and might give you solutions which won't work on any other list in the world

Comment: @Qohelet That was am arbitrary example, not a real use case.

Answer (score 0):

Build a new list with a list comprehension:

```
new_items = [4 if x==3 else x for x in l]
```

You can modify the original list in-place if you want, but it doesn't actually save time:

```
items = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
for index, item in enumerate(items):
    if (item ==3 2):
        items[index] = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

you can assign "some.thing.very.far.away.list" to a temporary variable and apply replace function

```
some.thing.very.far.away.list  = temp
something.very.far.away.list = temp.replace(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be a trick:

First define a dictionary with values you want to replace, than use a list comprehension using dictionary `get` with a default value.
You are passing `el` both as a key of the dictionary and as default value. If the key is found the corresponding value will be replaced otherwise the default value itself.

```py
>>> l = [0, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> rpl = {1: 23, 6: 12}
>>> [rpl.get(el, el) for el in l]
[0, 23, 2, 4, 4, 5, 12, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use map method to iterate and replace certain value.
> syntax : map(function, iterable, ...)
> The returned value from map() (map object) can then be passed to functions like list() (to create a list), set() (to create a set) and so on.

```
l = list(range(10))
replacing = 3
l =  list(map(lambda x: 4 if x == replacing else x, l)) # iterating over list l and replacing certain value using map method and converting map object in to another list.
print(l)
```

> output = [0, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

it takes two parameter function and iterable. map() passes each item of the iterable to this function.
where lambda function takes argument x from sequence (l), assign 4 if x is equal to 4 .
to know more about map method [Python map()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/map)